# Parse a multi-dimensional JSON file with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to parse this JSON file with jquery to access the "onpage" field that is set to "true". Then use the other fields in that item (desc, icon, name & url). I can get to "items" but can figure out how to get to "onpage" inside "items".
Thanks

```
[
{
    "group": "Home",
    "url": "http://www.home.com/"
},
{
    "group": "Production",
    "items": [
        {
            "onpage": true,
            "desc": "View local trails",
            "icon": "img/trails.png",
            "name": "Trails",
            "url": "https://www.home.com/go/Trails"
        },
        {
            "onpage": false,
            "desc": "Edit local trail",
            "icon": "img/traileditor.png",
            "name": "Trail Editor",
            "url": "https://www.home.com/go/Editor/"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've parsed it, you have an array with two objects in it. The second of those objects has a property, `items`, which is an array of objects. The first entry in that `items` array has `onpage` equal to `true`. So the direct path is:

```
itemWithOnPageTrue = theParsedData[1].items[0];
```

If you needed to find it, you'd probably use a pair of loops:

```
var itemWithOnPageTrue;
$.each(theParsedData, function() {
    var found;
    if (this.items) {
        $.each(this.items, function() {
            if (this.onpage) {
                itemWithOnPageTrue = this;
                found = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (found) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

[`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) will stop looping if you return false, which is why we do that when we find the first match. If you don't return anything or return a different value, it will keep looping.

Once you have `itemWithOnPageTrue`, you can access its other properties, like `itemWithOnPageTrue.desc`, `itemWithOnPageTrue.icon`, etc.

Comment: So to access `onpage` he would do `theParsedData[1].items[0].onpage`

Comment: @AlexW: Yes, but he wanted the object it's a part of.